# Amazon DynamoDB - modify indexes - copy data from table to table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I must change the Key Schema of a DynamoDB table. In [in the official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html) it is clearly written that:

> You cannot add, modify or delete indexes using UpdateTable. Indexes can only be defined at table creation time.

I was thinking of creating a new table (with the correct indexes) and migrating the data from the existing to the new one. Is there any tool that I can use for that? I have used [DynamoDBtoCSV](https://github.com/edasque/DynamoDBtoCSV) but it only supports export.

Comment: how much data are we talking here? what's the size of the current table?

Comment: @ChenHarel 2 million records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with EMR and Hive.

See the [Export, Import, Query, and Join Tables in DynamoDB Using Amazon EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMRforDynamoDB.html) walk throu from the Amazon EMR Developer Guide.